# Python/argparse: How to make an argument (i.e. --clear) don't warn me "error: too few arguments"?

Tags: python, argparse

I have this cmd line parsing stuf and I need to make "--clear" a valid unique parameter. However I'm getting an "Error: Too few arguments" when I only use "--clear" as an unique parameter.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            prog="sl",
            formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, 
            description="Shoot/Project launcher application",
            epilog="")            
parser.add_argument("project", metavar="projectname", 
                    help="Name of the project/shot to use")   
parser.add_argument("-p", metavar="project_name", 
                    help="Name of the project")
parser.add_argument("-s", metavar="shot_name",
                    help="Name of the shot")
parser.add_argument("--clear",action='store_true', 
                    help="Clear the information about the current selected project")
parser.add_argument("--test",   
                    help="test parameter")
args=parser.parse_args()
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Update:
Trying to answer some questions of the comments.
When I launch the app like:
sl project
it works fine.
But if I launch it like:
sl --clear 
I got a simple "sl: error: too few arguments"

Comment: How does the command line look, which produces the error?!
python main.py projectname --clear  or python main.py --clear?

Comment: try to use `docopt` instead of `argparse`. It's much more better and easier to use!

Comment: akaRem - What's the `docopt` equivalent for this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--clear` argument is not the problem here; `project` is a required argument.

If you should be able to call your program without naming a project, make `project` optional by adding `nargs='?'`:

```
parser.add_argument("project", metavar="projectname",
                    help="Name of the project/shot to use", nargs='?')
```

If it is an error to not specify a project name when other command-line switches are used, do so explicitly after parsing:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.clear and args.project is None:
    parser.error('Please provide a project')
```

Calling [`parser.error()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error) prints the error message, the help text and exits with return code 2:

```
$ python main.py --clear
Namespace(clear=True, p=None, project=None, s=None, test=None)
$ python main.py
usage: sl [-h] [-p project_name] [-s shot_name] [--clear] [--test TEST]
          [projectname]
sl: error: Please provide a project
```

Answer (score -1):

Add default values for each argument (--clear is no exception)

Comment: All arguments already have a `None` default value.  `--clear` as `store-true` has, by definition, `False` default.  The lack of user defined defaults does not cause errors.